# use the same button and change text on it: for my show/hide jquery function

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to display/hide on click of the button my contact form.
I have following "show - hide" jquery function with two buttons now and I cannot find out how to extend it so it would use the same button for both show and hide and reflected the visibility of the form with its message:

- on the first click on button "Write me" it shows the form and changes the button's text to  "I don't want to write any message now".
- on another click it hides the form and returns back to "Write me"

  ```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#hide").click(function(){
    $("#par").hide();
    });
    $("#show").click(function(){
    $("#par").show();
    });
    });
    </script>

  <button id="hide">Hide</button>
  <button id="show">Write me</button>
  <div id="par">
  <p>
  <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" autofocus required>
  </p>
  <p>
      <input type="text" name="subject" id="name" placeholder="subject" autofocus required>
  </p>
  <p>
      <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="message" autofocus required>
  </p>
  <p>
      <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send">
  </p>
  </div>


  #par{display:none;}
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#hide').on('click', function () {
        if ($('#par').is(':visible')) {
            $(this).text('Write me');
            $('#par').hide();
        } else {
            $(this).text("I don't want to write any message now.");
            $('#par').show();
        }
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Alfie/akAn5/)

Answer (score 1):

```
 $("#hide").toggle(function(){
  $("#par").hide();
  $(this).text("I don't want to write any message now");
  },function(){
$(this).text("Write me");
$("#par").show();
});
```

reference **[toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)**

Comment: **Note** .toggle(function, function, ... ) removed in jQuery 1.9+ http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#btn').click(function(){
  if($(this).text() == "hide")
  {
     $(this).text("show");
     $("#par").hide();
  }
  else
  {
     $(this).text("hide");
     $("#par").show();    
  }    
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, then you're looking for [**`.text()`**](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Remove those 2 buttons and have a single button like this

```
<button id="showHide">Show</button>
```

**JS:**

```
$("#showHide").click(function () {
    $("#par").toggle();
    if ($('#par').is(':visible')) {
        $("#showHide").text("Show");
    } else {
        $("#showHide").text("Hide");
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

### Try this out:- http://jsfiddle.net/adiioo7/E3YCm/

**JS:-**

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
      $("#button").click(function () {
          $("#par").toggle(function () {
              if ($("#button").val() == "Hide") $("#button").val("Show");
              else $("#button").val("Hide");
          });
      });
  });
```

**HTML:-**

```
<div id="par">Show/Hide Text</div>
<input type="button" id="button" value="Hide">
```

**CSS:-**

```
#par {
    display:none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're after [.toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/),

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#toggle").click(function(){
        $("#par").toggle();
        $("#toggle").text($("#toggle").text() == 'Hide' ? 'Show' : 'Hide');
    });
});
</script>

<button id="toggle">Show</button>
<div id="par">
<p>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email" autofocus required>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="text" name="subject" id="name" placeholder="subject" autofocus required>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="text" name="message" id="message" placeholder="message" autofocus required>
</p>
<p>
    <input type="submit" name="send" id="send" value="Send">
</p>
</div>

<style>
#par{
  display:none;
}
</style>
```